# How to preserve the timestamp of the original photo when exporting from CaptureOne?

Tags: capture-one

After I made some processing to a photo, I want to export it such that I can add it to other photo app.

[image]

However the exported image file does not carry the timestamp of the original file. Its creation time reflects the moment the export process was triggered.

Is there anyway I can change the timestamp the output file as part of the export process?

Comment: The original image capture date/time should still be preserved in the EXIF info. Pretty much any photo application can sort files using that field in the EXIF info. What problem are you having that requires the separate file metadata in your computer's database to be altered to match the original image capture timestamp?

Comment: PNG does not support EXIF

Comment: Why in the world would you use PNG for exporting such a photo?

Comment: @AnthonyKong No longer true since 2017. See [How to add author and other properties to PNG files?](//photo.stackexchange.com/a/75716)

Answer (score 0):

It's quite normal, the Time stamp is related to the digital file, and you created this jpeg file.
If you want to change the time stamp of a digital file, you should use software related to your OS that for.
In Mac OS, you can use bash commands, such as SetFile. You'll find plenty of resources on line that for.
exiftool is another possibility